# Command line redirection in dr. Java

Tags: java, redirect, stdin, piping

I want to input a lot `doubles` from a text file. This has to be done using piping. 
Right now I have this:

```
public class Average
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double sum=0.0;
        int cnt = 0;
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty())
        {
            double value=StdIn.readDouble();
            sum += value;
            cnt++;
        }
        double average=sum/cnt;
        StdOut.println("Average is " + average);
    }
}
```

To execute this I write following command:

> $ java Average < data.txt

The problem is that it doesn't work. It asks for more input and then calculates the average of just that input. How do I get it to calculate the average of the values in data.txt?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @Adalcar I'm sorry. Im really quite new to java (I prefer VBA) and I haven't gotten the jist of the jargon yet... Could you elaborate?

Comment: I was wondering what IDE you were using/which command prompt you were writing your `java Average < data.txt` command into, since it is valid syntax in bash but I do not know whether other environments use the same syntax.

Comment: @Adalcar I use dr. Java if that is what you mean. I execute it from the build in command prompt in Dr. Java

Comment: My bad, so as far as I can read in the documentation, it is nowhere implied that files can be piped into a program like that. Where did you find that method?

Comment: @Adalcar well it's an example straight from my book (an introduction to java, an interdisciplinary approach) 
My school asks us to just use dr. Java (I have no idea why) and I've seen my teacher do it... When I asked her all I got was a "oh I don't know either".

Comment: If I understand it right it should become arguments on the command line when it's piped in the program but it just doesn't want to work :(

Comment: Well I can't install Dr.java here so I can't help you for now, i'll try on my own PC in a few hours and check what's wrong. This syntax is a normal pipe syntax in bash and should work, but it is obviously ignoring the input...

Comment: That would be freaking awesome, thank you ever so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, you are using the built-in `Command Prompt` from Dr. Java, which does not support redirections.

You have to use the `Command Prompt` program on your PC, and get to your environment according to [this procedure(part 4 and 5)](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/windows/).

Comment: Thank you very much! I am really grateful for your help!

I wasn't too sure about stack overflow but you just proofed me wrong, thank you!